# How is delta v from earth to venus calculated?

Tags: physics

Trying to do hohmann transfers from earth to venus and getting a a total delta v of around 6km/s. Every source online seems to be saying 3.5km/s. Can someone show how the delta v to get to venus and the capture manoeuvre are calculated?

Comment: Your question *might* be better suited for https://astronomy.stackexchange.com, but make sure to read their FAQ first.

Comment: @MartinR I've since voted to close as off-topic there. But luckily [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) is a perfect home for this kind of question (once flushed out with more detail)

Comment: hi @j1nkso *welcome to Stack Exchange!* There are [almost 200 SE sites to choose from](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) and it is sometimes hard to figure out which questions are best asked on which sites. Don't worry if this question is closed here as off-topic, and also asking the identical question on multiple sites ("cross-posting") is discouraged for several reasons including answer fragmentation. It might be best if you delete it here, and then wait for the copy in Astronomy SE to be migrated to Space SE after you add those details I've mentioned there.